# 2 PCs playing same game require to download patch 2 times, any solution?

Tags: pc, guild-wars-2

This is quite bad: me and my girlfriend both play Guild Wars 2. She just downloaded a patch of 1GB on her PC, and now to play I have to download it again or copy paste it from her computer.

Are there any solution to avoid this, like sharing the game directory? Notice that we have 2 different computers (but we are on the same network).

If it's possible, how's big the performance loss? I'm getting really mad updating the game from the network. I don't even understand why it can't use my LAN as a P2P support which can insanely speed up my download (because she already downloaded the patch).

Comment: I don't think the question is really focused on guild wars 2...

Comment: Given that different games can handle patching in all sorts of different ways (some of which may allow for patch copying, and some of which may not), I'm not sure what kind of generalized "share patches across machines" solution could exist that would apply equally to all games. But if any answers suggesting such a solution pop up, by all means, feel free to retag.

Comment: If there is a way, I would not recommend it. I don't believe the game was made to be executed that way, what if your game instance modifies some variables which are the same that your girlfriend are using? Consequences would never be the same.

Comment: Yea, that's a good point. However Guild Wars 2 doesn't store settings in same directories of the game, so it's not a big trouble in that case.

Comment: And what's the point of -1 on my question? I don't see it being outside of game.stackexchange policies, seems also a resonable question -.-'

Comment: I think just updating on both comps is the best way to go. But perhaps you can share the GW2 folder on a Home Sharing Network thats built into Winodws (assuming thats what you are running)

Comment: Yea that is my idea, but I'm afraid of performance loss.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL Well you'll never know until you try it ;) considering LAN networks speed are fast I highly doubt you will notice any performance loss from sharing the GW2 folder other than slightly longer loading times.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk: If you post it as an answer, I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the GW2 folder on a Home Shared Network will let everyone on the network access the files and only require a download once.

Comment: Make sure to use a cabled network.

Comment: Doesn't it add excessive weight to the storing machine? GW2 is quite resource consuming...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to do this, you would stop your computer from patching and copy the fully patched GW2.dat file from her computer to yours. Make sure to back up your file before overwriting, of course.

Comment: The asker is specifically asking if there's a way around it that *doesn't* involve copy pasting it.

Comment: The suggested method has a big problem: If my girlfriend starts playing the game, I can't copy (file opened). Basically, if she patch before me I have to wait she stops playing to copy the file.

Comment: @fbueckert Ah, I missed that part due to the mention of using the LAN as P2P.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL Why not ask your GF to stop playing? It is not like it will take a long time... or are you that whipped? :p

Comment: It's bad asking to stop playing when she just started... And anyway, depending if she is in dungeon or not I can't ask her to stop

Comment: +1: This is the correct answer: copy'n'paste over the LAN *is* peer-to-peer networking by definition.

Comment: I'm confused, why does she have to stop playing? If her gw2 folder is shared you should be able to copy it to your hard drive while she's playing. It's not like you're deleting any files ...

Comment: Files and directories can be locked by programs when they are using them, even preventing you from copying the files. Not sure if this is true with GW2, but I'm assuming the asker has tried and that it's the case.

Comment: @horatio: No, that's not true. If the pathing file is able to use a P2P connection to patch my game it will download only 1 GB from my girlfriend PC. Instead, in this way, I have to copy 15GB which, even through the network, takes around the same amount of time downloading 1GB

Comment: @Coronus: Yes, I've already tried it and it works in that way.

Comment: robocopy can sync folders. Note that 100Mbit ethernet is faster than your internet